# IBM MQ JMS connection not established from eclipse spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have been getting the issue of JMS connection refreshed from a few days.
Previously I was able to connect to the MQ and the same spring boot java code was working fine.

Now, the war file I build and deploy in the IBM Websphere also works. But it doesnt connect from Eclipse IDE. New to IBM MQ. Please help.

```
 Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'testq_OUT' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSCC0008: This connection is closed.
2022-03-10 14:44:28,659 INFO org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] Established shared JMS Connection: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection@3d803c95
2022-03-10 14:44:28,659 INFO org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
2022-03-10 14:44:34,767 WARN org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'testq_OUT' - trying to recover. Cause: com.ibm.mq.MQException.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)V
2022-03-10 14:44:34,768 INFO org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
2022-03-10 14:44:40,788 WARN org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'testq_OUT' - trying to recover. Cause: com.ibm.mq.MQException.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)V
2022-03-10 14:44:40,788 INFO org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3] Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

[Please check the stack trace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXPJS.png)

Comment: On the surface it looks like its a sequence error in your code, ie. closing the connection too early, but its odd that its only occurring in the IDE. Check the MQ server logs, that may show an Open, followed by a Close, followed by a Post or Get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that some jms jars are not picked up from maven repo by the ide. so tried adding them on the build path and this works!